# Contingency tables after multiply imputated data with MICE in R

Tags: r, contingency, r-mice, imputation

After imputation in R with the [MICE](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf) package, I want to generate contingency tables. The fit shows the tables in a list, but if I  `pool()` them, the following error is thrown: `Error in pool(fit) : Object has no coef() method.` What am I doing wrong?

This basic example reproduces the error:

```
library("mice")

imp <- mice(nhanes)
fit <- with(imp, table(bmi, hyp))
est <- pool(fit)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `mice::pool(object)` simply calculated estimates and standard errors for scalar estimands using "Rubin's rules", for which it relies on the fact that the estimates are often extracted using `coef(object)`, and the standard errors of these estimates are usually available in the diagonal of `vcov(object)`. It is intended to be used with objects of classes like `lm`, which have `coef` and `vcov` methods neatly defined.

In your example, Rubin's rules do not apply. What are the "estimates" and "standard errors" of the entries in a contingency table? For this reason, `pool` complains that there is no method available for extracting the coefficients from your `fit`.

So if your "estimate" is simply supposed to be the "average" contingency table, try this:

```
library("mice")

imp <- mice(nhanes)
fit <- with(imp, table(bmi, hyp))
est <- pool(fit) 

# dimensions
nl <- length(fit$analyses)
nr <- nrow(fit$analyses[[1]])
nc <- ncol(fit$analyses[[1]])

# names
rnames <- rownames(fit$analyses[[1]])
cnames <- colnames(fit$analyses[[1]])

# cast list to array
fit.arr <- array(unlist(fit$analyses), dim=c(nr,nc,nl), 
                 dimnames=list(rnames,cnames))

# get "mean" contingency table
apply(fit.arr, 1:2, mean)

#        1   2
# 20.4 1.8 0.0
# 21.7 1.4 0.0
# 22   1.4 0.2
# 22.5 1.8 0.4
# 22.7 1.2 0.4
# 24.9 1.2 0.0
# 25.5 1.0 1.6
# 26.3 0.0 1.0
# 27.2 0.4 1.0
# 27.4 1.4 0.4
# 27.5 1.6 0.2
# 28.7 0.0 1.0
# 29.6 1.0 0.2
# 30.1 1.8 0.2
# 33.2 1.0 0.0
# 35.3 1.2 0.2
```

Whether or not the "average" table is of any use, however, is probably debatable.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is it also debatable to calculate a mean from an imputed column, and if so, why?

Comment: For the imputed data, no. The mean of a continuous variable has a sampling distribution that is approximately normal. As a result, using Rubin's rules will be reasonable. For the "columns" in the contingency table, however, the story is a bit different. For "contingencies" close to zero, I would find Rubin's rules inappropriate, but for values reasonably far from zero they might have good properties (see [the relationship between binomial and normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation)).